# Efficient way to get all commits relevant to a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's say I have a complicated octopus merge between the branches `A`, `B`, and `C` below:

```
---1---o---A
    \ /
     X
    / \
---2---o---o---B
            \
             o---C
```

This is similar to what is described in http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion

I can easily obtain `1` and `2` from git, using `git merge-base --all --octopus A B C`

What I really need is ALL of the pictured commits.

I can do this manually by:

```
git log --pretty=format:%H A...1
git log --pretty=format:%H A...2
git log --pretty=format:%H B...1
git log --pretty=format:%H B...2
git log --pretty=format:%H C...1
git log --pretty=format:%H C...2
```

And then taking the set union of the commits, but this is horribly inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way of producing this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--ancestry-path` is built to do exactly that:

```
git log --pretty=%H --ancestry-path A B C --not $(git merge-base --all --octopus A B C)
git merge-base --all --octopus A B C
```

(I wish there was an `--inclusive` option for log, having it include all explicitly-marked bottom commits, until then those have to be listed with a separate command.)